# Handle intent_send from same application

Tags: android

I have an `intent filter` on one of my activities like so:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
<data android:mimeType="text/*" />
<data android:mimeType="application/*" />
<data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

and in the same application, I call action_send, but my application does not appear in the chooser (it appears from anywhere else).
So my question is: is there a way I can handle action_share called by my app from my own app?

Edit:
Here is the intent code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                        .setType("application/*")
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(newFile))
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "upload file..."));
```

Comment: Could you please share the code you're using to trigger intent?

Comment: Show your share intent code

Comment: `File newFile = new File(file.getUri().getPath());
 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                            .setType("application/*")
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  Uri.fromFile(newFile))
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "upload file..."));`